# Python 3 pygame: cannot import pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to make this snake game, but it said the following error when I did:

```
imported pygame:
```

I get an Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you run `pip install pygame` or `pip3 install pygame` depending on which version of python you use?

Comment: I didn't run any of those.

Comment: I will run them right now... it says that I can't download pygame because the administrator does not allow it

Comment: Try with `--user` flag

Comment: I tried that and then run the program, but it says that there is no module called pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frist see if pygame is installed using

```
pip3 freeze
```

if not, then install it:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

now `import pygame` won't raise error.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: pip is installed